Why Serial output data not showing using CH9102F?
I have hardware electronics, custom designed, that use the IC CH9102F for USB to UART communications. On Arduino Studio 2.x for Windows 11 it uploads fine the firmware code however when I want to see the serial output on the serial monitor, it shows nothing.

see the hardware electronics in this repository on Github:
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/PCB-Prototyping-Catalogue/blob/main/Smart%20DAQ/16-bit/

It's worth checking your hardware too. Check for manufacturing errors.

always true.  ;)

Upon analysis and evaluation of this issue, I found on the driver settings the following option that must be disabled, Disable ModemHandShake, for serial output to correctly output data (see the snapshot below for more detailed information on the settings.


Interesting. I have an unresponsive I/O issue with an (unrelated) UART IC where it only works when the driver instantiates in Windows if the hardware behind the UART is already powered on. Shouldn't be the case though; the PC-side of the UART is USB bus powered. I wonder if this is the solution. Thanks for sharing.

sure ! hope it solves your issue
